# Extract after equal sign in php

Tags: php

i am working on some code where i am getting the output as show below

```
all-box=1
```

i want to extract all the value from it after equal sign and input in to some other variable to more forward.
i tried it using the php explode method which gives the output as shown below.

> Array ( [0] => all-box [1] => 1 )

By doing this way it is increasing my steps.could anyone please tell me how i will extract the values after equal sign in easy way.

Comment: [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) / [`parse_ini_string`](http://php.net/parse_ini_string). You know, `explode` isn't the epitome of PHP programming.

Comment: @mario turns out that's what OP wanted after all...

Comment: @Nick The string looks like some CSS remnant or whatever. Without context it's hard to tell which approach would be more reliable. But probably just a workaround anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `list` operator on the left-hand-side of the assignment to assign directly to a variable:

```
list (, $value) = explode('=', 'all-box=1');
echo $value;
```

Or just use the array index directly on the output of `explode`:

```
$value = explode('=', 'all-box=1')[1];
echo $value;
```

In both cases the output is `1`.

To get an array whose key is `all-box` and value is `1`, use `parse_str`:

```
parse_str('all-box=1', $array);
print_r($array);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/L9Pke)

Comment: could you please tell me how i will make this all-box=1 into an array where all-box is key and 1 is it value

Comment: @ZahidHussain use `parse_str('all-box=1', $array)` (as suggested by mario)